# Can we Disassemble the Mask of the Dragon Queen?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, published-adventures, rise-of-tiamat

We just finished the *Rise of Tiamat* Hardcover and we got the Mask of the Dragon Queen, but without the Black Dragon Mask since one of our party members has it.

**Can we disassemble the Mask of the Dragon Queen so at least most of us has a mask each?**

Worst case scenario is we give it to the one who has the Black Dragon Mask so that he can complete it.

Answer (score 6):

## Rules-As-Written

There are no rules in ***Rise of Tiamat*** (or any other source) for how to put the mask together *or* how to take it apart. The description only indicates what happens if you *do*. Silly, perhaps, but that's what's written.

In an non-Adventurers League game, your GM can allow or disallow breaking up the mask as he likes.

## Adventurers League Considerations

For Adventurers League characters prior to Season 8, expect table variation. While WoTC has released stats for the individual masks, only the *Black Dragon Mask* shows up in a "Treasure" entry, which means it's the only lootable one in ***RoT***. For AL purposes a table DM would be entirely correct in a belief that the individual masks do not exist and are not lootable.

When Season 8 starts at the end of August 2018, the Mask of the Dragon Queen is on the [problematic items list](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/news/changes-dd-adventurers-league-rewards). If the character has finished ***Rise of Tiamat*** with a mask, it is converted to Treasure Points. If they're still in the adventure, it becomes a story item that will be gone at the end of the adventure.

Comment: And remember that AL rules do not need to make sense. They exist to allow a common ground for several tables with random people that would otherwise be unmixable (either the people or the tables, your pick). For home play, following AL rules might be silly. A crafty DM could extrapolate the other masks from the black one.